# No se puede obtener acceso al objeto desechado. Nombre del objeto: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'

Tags: c#, socket

Llevo bastantes días con un problema que no consigo resolver, espero que algún alma caritativa descubra el error. Estoy utilizando sockets para mandar mensajes y recibirlos de un servidor, el caso es que cuando intento abrir el socket por segunda vez me da la siguiente excepcion:

> No se puede obtener acceso al objeto desechado. Nombre del objeto:
>   'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.

El código es el siguiente, la línea donde me para el programa con la excepción es:

```
Socket envio = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

Código completo:

```
#region TCP CLIENTE
// INICIALIZAR PROCEDIMIENTO
public void INITCPCliente()
{
    btntcpASocket.Enabled = true;
    btntcpCSocket.Enabled = false;
    btnTCPCEnviar.Enabled = false;
    txttcpResultados.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
}
// BOTON ABRIR SOCKET
public void btntcpASocket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hiloTCPCliente = new Thread (tcpCliente);
    hiloTCPCliente.Start();
}

Socket envio = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
public void tcpCliente()
{
    actualizarUI("Intentando conectar a " + txttcpIP.Text + " : " + txttcpPuerto.Text);
    try
    {
        envio.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(txttcpIP.Text), Convert.ToInt16(txttcpPuerto.Text));
        if (envio.Connected)
        {
            btntcpASocket.Enabled = false;
            btnTCPCEnviar.Enabled = true;
            btntcpCSocket.Enabled = true;
            actualizarUI("Conectado");
        }
        else
        {
            actualizarUI("No se pudo conectar...");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        actualizarUI(error.Message);
    }
}

// BOTON CERRAR SOCKET
private void btntcpCSocket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    envio.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    envio.Close();

    if (!envio.Connected)
    {
        btntcpASocket.Enabled = true;
        btnTCPCEnviar.Enabled = false;
        btntcpCSocket.Enabled = false;
        actualizarUI("Desconectado");
    }           
}

// BOTON ENVIAR TRAMA
private void btnTCPCEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Thread hilo = new Thread(EnvioRecibo);
    hilo.Start();
}

private void EnvioRecibo()
{
    try
    {
        //Buffer de datos de servidor
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        //Envio de datos a servidor
        byte[] mensaje = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtASCII.Text);
        actualizarUI("Edu Tool -> " + txtASCII.Text);
        int bytesSent = envio.Send(mensaje);
        txtTCPCEnviados.Text = ("Bytes enviados : " + Convert.ToString(mensaje.Length));
        //Recibir datos de servidor
        int bytesRecibidos = envio.Receive(bytes);
        actualizarUI("Servidor <- " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRecibidos));
        txtTCPCRecibidos.Text = ("Bytes recibidos : " + bytesRecibidos);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        actualizarUI("El servidor no devolvio ningun dato...");
    }
}

// MESANJES EN TCP CLIENTE
public void actualizarUI(string s)
{
    Func<int> del = delegate ()
    {
        txttcpResultados.AppendText(s + Environment.NewLine);
        return 0;
    };
    Invoke(del);
}
```

---

creo que me he explicado mal... El código funciona, incluso abro bien el socket (instanciando el objeto) mando telegramas y las recibo, y lo cierro... Con el método "envío.Close().
El problema viene que al intentar abrirlo otra vez, si intento instanciar "envío" otra vez, después de haberlo cerrado, me salta esa excepción. No se como operar ya que si lo he cerrado debería poder abrirlo otra vez, pero no se como...

Comment: Es un poco extraño tu código. El socket `envio` en principio solo se está definiendo una vez, con lo que es raro que la excepción te la lance en la linea que dices. Intenta añadir en tu método `tcpCliente()` lo siguiente en la primera linea del try: `envio = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);`

Comment: ¿Alguna idea?
A ver si alguien me da un rayo de esperanza... :P

Comment: Probaste lo que te dije en mi comentario?

Comment: Hola Pikoh, si meto eso dentro del try me salen errores por todos los sitios donde utilizo "envio", ya que no estan accesibles a la declaracion (dentro del try)

Comment: Al ser `Socket` derivado de `IDisposable` tu problema está en que lo instancias una sola vez y al llamar a `Close()` o `Dispose()` ya no puedes usar más esa instancia. La solución sería que cada vez se cree una instancia nueva o en su defecto, limitarte a llamar a `Connect()` y `Disconnect()` para reutilizarlo. No cargo respuesta ya que desconozco el uso de `Sockets` y hablo en base a lo leído en la documentación.

Answer (score 0):

Si lanzas el proceso en un Thread separado, podrías cerrar y eliminar las variables al terminarlo, desde el propio hilo.

Puedes probar tambien a no ejecutar en un hilo separado para hacer debug más facilmente.

Antes de asignar y cerrar comprueba el valor asignado.

[Ejemplo de tratamiento de hilo](https://programsnippets.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/sample-to-create-start-pause-resume-and-terminate-a-thread-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

En tu método `btntcpCSocket_Click()` invocas `envio.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);` y seguido de `envio.Close();`

`envio.Close()` libera todos los recursos del socket, tanto los de tipo *managed* como *unmanaged*. Desde ese momento ya no puedes volver a utilizar la misma instancia de `Socket`, tienes que crear una nueva.

La línea `Socket envio = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);` conviértela en sólo la declaración de la variable, `Socket envio;`. Luego, en la función `tcpCliente()`, cuando vayas a abrir la conexión es cuando debes crear la instancia del socket utilizando `envio = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);`